# Can this Random code be simplified without Arrays or Loops?

Tags: java, random

```
public String generateCardNo(int expiryDay, int expiryMonth, char firstNameInitial, char   surnameInitial)
{ 
    int firstNameInitialNumber = formatInitial(firstNameInitial);
    int surnameInitialNumber = formatInitial(surnameInitial);

    Random rand = new Random();

    int num1 = 4 + rand.nextInt(5);
    int num2 = (expiryDay + expiryMonth) % 10;
    int num3 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num4 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num5 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num6 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num7 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num8 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num9 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num10 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num11 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num12 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num13 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num14 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num15 = (firstNameInitialNumber + surnameInitialNumber) % 10;
    int num16 = (num1 + num5 + num11) % 10;

   String cardNumStr = "" + num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num12 + num13 + num14 + num15 + num16;

    return cardNumStr;
```

I am making random int's with a range of 0-9 and am wondering if I can simplify the code without using arrays or loops.

I know there is a method where you can use

```
    int num3To7 = rand.nextInt(100000);
```

And then format the decimal(or number) to (######)

Are there any other methods of simplifying this that you guys can think of?
I can't use loops or arrays because I am not allowed to.

Comment: Why not make an array?

Comment: Are you only trying to get 5 random numbers? If that is the case, you could set a random bit in a long like this: set the 1st-9th bit, set the 10th-19th bit etc. Long has 64 bits so you could get 6 random numbers from 0-9

Comment: Since this is obviously homework, can we see the whole assignment please? Otherwise we cannot tell you how to simplify the code. If all you really want to do is assign five `int` variables to random numbers then there is no simpler way.

Comment: Updated the example so you guys understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that num16 is dependent on num5 and num11.  That forces you to break up the otherwise uniform run between num3 and num14.  (You couldn't do them all in one go anyway because that's bigger than an int.  We could have played with BigInteger but oh well).

Here's how I'd do it if I wasn't trying to be fancy:

```
public String generateCardNo(int expiryDay, int expiryMonth, char firstNameInitial, char   surnameInitial)
{ 
    int firstNameInitialNumber = formatInitial(firstNameInitial);
    int surnameInitialNumber = formatInitial(surnameInitial);

    Random rand = new Random();

    int num1 = 4 + rand.nextInt(5);
    int num2 = (expiryDay + expiryMonth) % 10;
    int num3to4 = rand.nextInt(100);
//  int num4 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num5 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num6to10 = rand.nextInt(100000);
//  int num7 = rand.nextInt(10);
//  int num8 = rand.nextInt(10);
//  int num9 = rand.nextInt(10);
//  int num10 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num11 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num12to14 = rand.nextInt(1000); 
//  int num13 = rand.nextInt(10);
//  int num14 = rand.nextInt(10);
    int num15 = (firstNameInitialNumber + surnameInitialNumber) % 10;
    int num16 = (num1 + num5 + num11) % 10;

   String cardNumStr = "" + num1 
                          + num2 
                          + String.format("%02d", num3to4) 
                          + num5 
                          + String.format("%05d", num6to10 
                          + num11 
                          + String.format("%03d", num12to14) 
                          + num15 
                          + num16;

    return cardNumStr;
}
```

Comment: The thing is though that when "int num3To4 = rand.nextInt(100);" it can generate a loss in numbers. What if it generates 6? Then a number is missing.

Comment: Maybe if I were to do something like "int num3To4 = 10 + rand.nextInt(90);" it would take numbers between 10 and 99... However it restricts the randomness as I can not generate "06".

Comment: Is there some reason 06 isn't the same as "0" + "6"?

Comment: The string returns a 16 digit number. If "int num3To4 = rand.nextInt(100);" is used, then I could possibly end up with only 15 digits right?

Comment: Think some zero padding might take care of that?

Comment: Probably I have not used it before can u add an example in the response? I see its in already :)

Comment: An example?  You mean like: `System.out.println(String.format("%02d", 1));`?

Comment: No its good actually. This was the kind of solution I was really looking for!

Comment: While this is probably exactly what your instructor wanted, as a professional developer I feel compelled to point out that this is NOT simpler.  This creates code that is less flexible and harder to maintain for no better reason then reducing lines of code.  In short, please don't code like this professionally.

Answer (score 1):

For num3 to num14, you could go

`int num3to14 = rand.nextInt(1000000000000);`

except that's too big of an int.  So go

```
int num3to8 = rand.nextInt(1000000);
int num9to13 = rand.nextInt(100000);
```

Double check the number of zeros, may be off there...

Unfortunately, you'll need to calc num16 differently since num5 and num11 are gone.

**Note**: I'm assuming a typo in your code explains the missing num4.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to simplifying this:
`"" + num1 + num2 + num3 + num3 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9 + num10 + num11 + num12 + num13 + num14 + num15 + num16;`. If you are using Java 8 you have access to the stream API. You can therefore do something like the following:

```
 final Random rand = new Random();
 String cardNum = Integer.toString(IntStream.generate(() -> rand.nextInt(10)).limit(16).sum)
```

Edit: I noticed after writing that solution that some of the `num`s are not just a random number between 0 and 9. To combat this you could simply lower the limit of the steam and add the special cases inside the `Integer.to string(into)` method

Extra info: It has come to my attention that the `Random` class had some extra implementation in Java 8; you can now do the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int sum = rand.ints(0,10).limit(16).sum;
```

This creates an IntStream of Random integers between 0 and 10 then limits it to 16 ints, proceeding to sum these said ranfoms.

Comment: I am going to look further into this it seems like a good way to go about this.

Comment: The `Stream` API along with lambdas are a huge improvement to Java in 8. Take a look at my answer again as I realised there is an easier way to go about this, again. The Random class got new methods added in J8.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is a bit unclear but if i got it correctly, you want to get a 5 digit formatted String in the end.

Here's how I would do it:

```
int a = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 99999));
return String.format("%05d", a);
```

First of all you get a random():

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0.

Then multiply it by 99999 for example. Add 9's if you want more places. Then round it and format the string to for example 5 places which will add a zero in front if the random is 4 decimal places for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store all the random numbers making use of loops where you can.

```
public String generateCardNo(int expiryDay, int expiryMonth,
                             char firstNameInitial, char surnameInitial)
{ 
    int firstNameInitialNumber = formatInitial(firstNameInitial);
    int surnameInitialNumber = formatInitial(surnameInitial);

    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] num = new int[16];

    num[0] = 4 + rand.nextInt(5);
    num[1] = (expiryDay + expiryMonth) % 10;

    for(int index = 2; index <= 13; ++index) {
        num[index] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }

    int[14] = (firstNameInitialNumber + surnameInitialNumber) % 10;
    int[15] = (num[0] + num[4] + num[10]) % 10;

    // avoid string concatenation
    // use a string builder instead
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16);
    for (int digit : num) {
        sb.append(digit);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```